# URL Parameters what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, api, parameters

I'm trying to get information from the RIDB API (government recreation data). However, I'm confused on how to use the URL Parameters. I looked up examples and have tried many different things.

First, to start I have `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS/` which works just fine. I get a JSON result containing trail information, perfect. However if I try `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS/milesmin10` or `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS/milesmin=10` or `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS?milesmin=10` or `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS?milesmin10` as examples I get nothing back. As you can see from the attached image `milesmin` is an acceptable parameter, can someone explain how include these parameters in my code and/or what I'm obviously doing wrong.

[image: URL Parameters]

Comment: From what you've said, the endpoint ends with a slash, so adding a URL parameter after that should be: `http://ridb.recreation.gov/api.v1.trails/USFS/?milesmin=10`

Comment: `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS/?milesmin=10` & `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS?milesmin=10` both are working for me .

Comment: @NiteshVerma You're right. They do work, I realized that my URL was forming incorrectly as I was adding the API key on the end of the url, which is fine but I need the '&' sign before the key in order to keep it working. The answer marked as "best" solves those types of issues from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), and it worked fine.  You have to register for [their API key](https://ridb.recreation.gov/?action=register) in order to use this service.  The process was quick, and I had a key in less than 5 mins.  Here's the code that got the results.

```
import requests

# You must replace <your api key> with the key they give you
api = <your api key>
url = 'https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS/'

params = {'milesmin': 10, 'apikey': api}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)


#    In [168]: r.request.url
#    Out[168]: 'https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS/?milesmin=10&apikey=<your api key>'

#    In [169]: r.text[:500]
#    Out[169]: u'{"RECDATA":[{"TypicalTreadWidth":"N\\/A","MinimumTrailWidth":"N\\/A","TypicalTreadCrossSlope
#    ":"N\\/A","TerraMotorized":"N\\/A","AllowedSnowUse":"N\\/A","PackSaddleRestricted":"N\\/A",
#    "TrailSurface":"N\\/A","TrailNo":"8021SA","AllowedTerraUse":"N\\/A","XcountrySkiAccptDisc":"N\\/A",
#    "TrailUSFSID":20,"NonmotorWatercraftManaged":"N\\/A","XcountrySkiManaged":"N\\/A",
#    "BicycleManaged":"N\\/A","ShapeLength":0.5105766578900838,"MVUMSymbol":99,
#    "MotorcycleManaged":"N\\/A","GEOM":"LINESTRING (-111.69189874799997 39.9735'
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer shows a way to avoid the mistake I was making.
I had `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS?APIKEY` so when I added the params I had `https://ridb.recreation.gov/api/v1/trails/USFS?APIKEY?Params` which obviously doesn't work without using the "&" symbol in there. Your method is clearly superior so thank you!